# Image processing in pycuda

Tags: image-processing, struts2, jython, pycuda

I have designed a web site using Struts2. Now I have to call a function where image processing will be done. For that I have chosen to use *pycuda*. Can any one tell me steps and dependencies for installing pycuda. (I have to call this code from an action file). Does I need Jython also? I am using *centOS*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what image processing means here, but if you need to exploit the GPU to perform your calculations with Cuda, and you are using Java, then why using [*pycuda*](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda/) that is for Python ?

Use [JCuda](http://www.jcuda.org/) or [Cuda4J](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.71.doc/user/gpu_developing_cuda4j.html) - the J is there to help you :)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can we run Cuda4J on any system with GPU? Because I have downloaded java from ibm site but not able to install it.